# Bootstrap dropdown suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website mock up when all of a sudden the drop down menu disappeared. The version of CSS and JS I'm using are:

bootstrap.js + bootstrap.css v2.3.2
jQuery.js 1.9.1

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73042624/Testing/Page/home.html

I know the bootstrap drop down example is using jquery.js v.1.10 but I tested it with v.1.9.1 and it still works.

Anyone has any idea why my dropdown doesn't work?

THank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Its not broken at all. One of your elements is hiding its overflow.

Simply add this to your css:

```
.navbar .nav {
     overflow: visible;
 }
```

While a little basic I suggest you read this:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Or if you're feeling bold read this, as you'll learn more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools links. Posting alternatives like the MDN as you've done is far better for learning - W3Schools is full of mistakes and bad practices

Comment: indeed, thats why i recommend MDN. But, if this guy doesn't understand what o:h is then I think MDN is going to be a little confusing for him.

Comment: Possibly, but my view here is that, while a little difficult at the beginning, learning how to do things properly will do a lot of good later on. I've always found MDN's pages pretty easy to understand, and the examples are handy

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden`

**in your css file**

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73042624/Testing/common/css/common.css
```

**LIne no  199**

```
ul {
overflow: hidden; // remove this line
}
```

Comment: But he will need overflow hidden on his `UL` Its a nice reset to have.

Comment: but you cant set to ul overflow hidden in reset basically this is normal selector this is wrong. You can't set ul overflow hidden you jsut add a class than apply  ......

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. I've added overflow:hidden to the general ul when I wanted to add it to a specific ul to clear the float of the li. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is a big 'ol silly goose like me, I mistakenly updated Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 with my package manager.